# SP 2013 FBA Authentication failure: the http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'negotiate'

Tags: forms-authentication

I get the following error on the event viewer when trying to log on a Sharepoint website with forms-based authentication (FBA):

> The http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.

**Details**

- I've configured FBA using this tutorial (http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/)
- On IIS, the website's authentication is configured to only use forms-based authentitcation.
- Central Admin is configured to use Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation.
- Security Token Service is configured to only use forms-based authentitcation.

Comment: You configured the web.config of the application web? See this [article](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/).

Comment: Yes, I have configured the web.config of Application, Central Admin and Security Token Service, following precisely that tutorial. I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: Check the ULS logs for any additional errors? Also, see this post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704720/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-ntlm-the-a)

Comment: you shouldn't have to change anything through IIS. Web.config changes and further configuration straight from the central administration should be enough.